# Django: Per View authentication scheme

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework

The django rest framework does allow per view authentication schemes:

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#setting-the-authentication-scheme

I think this is handy and I ask myself why this gets reinvented in the django rest framework.

"Why does django not provide this?" is a question which would get closed here on stackoverflow soon.

That's why I ask:

How to get per view authentication schemes in django?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "Why does django not provide this?"

It's an opinion. I don't see why someone should limit a specific view to some authentication backends. Whatever my/your opinion is, the decision is made in Django/DRF. Contact their mailing list and search their bug repo to find out why a specific decision made.

> How to get per view authentication schemes in django?

Before anything be sure you know how Django works. Read all authentication related documents like [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/) and [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/auth/).

You could go the DRF way: Completely ditch Django authentication and write it yourself. Replace Django authentication backend abstract with your desired one and make a way to configure each view (e.g. Use a decorator to set attributes on you view function or use class based views + some fields). Then add a middleware to authenticate users and replace Django's `AuthenticationMiddleware` to provide `request.user`. You should also make sure that things like `login_required` work without modification or you should provide an alternative.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Django is a great framework and I think most of the time they solve things really well. That's why I think "You could go the DRF way: Completely ditch Django authentication and write it yourself." is a bad idea. On the other hand I guess the DRF developer have good reasons why they did it this way.